# How can I print out the filenames of all pdf files containing multiple keywords?

Tags: pdf

I have a directory with hundreds of PDFs. I want to output the filenames of all PDFs that contain multiple keywords, e.g. All PDFs containing "foo" and also containing "bar". [pdfgrep](https://pdfgrep.org/doc.html) can search for multiple expressions, but it's an OR instead of AND search.
How can I achieve this?

Tried with `pdfgrep --files-with-matches --ignore-case --with-filename --max-count 1 "(foo|bar)" -- *.pdf`, but that matches all files that have "foo" OR "bar", not AND.
Tried lookahead assertions, but that doesn't match if the keywords are on different pages within the PDF, `pdfgrep --files-with-matches --ignore-case --with-filename --max-count 1 --perl-regexp '^(?s:(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar))' -- *.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by passing the output from one pass into `xargs` and running in another pass; so filter all files containing "foo", then only search those for "bar":

```
pdfgrep --null --files-with-matches --ignore-case "foo" -- *.pdf | xargs -0 pdfgrep --files-with-matches --ignore-case "bar" --
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to perform and "AND" in a `grep` is using a pipe:

```
grep "foo" *.txt | grep "bar"
```

=> this shows all lines inside `*.txt`, containing both the words "foo" and "bar".